# Iteratively create new columns in r Function

Tags: r, dplyr

As a disclaimer, I rarely use any apply functions, and this might be the reason why I am struggling with this task.

I would like to create multiple new columns (say 5) within an R dataframe

imagine a dataset representing the daily closing price of the S&P500

`df <- data.frame(symbol = rep(S&P_500, n = 5), value =c(2500,2550,2560,2600,2400))`

If I wanted (inefficiently) to create 5 new variables, each indicating for each row, the lag value n, (n, 1:5)

I could do :

```
df %>%
mutate(S&P500_LAG_1 = lag(value, n=1),
       S&P500_LAG_2 = lag(value, n=2),
       S&P500_LAG_3 = lag(value, n=3),
       S&P500_LAG_4 = lag(value, n=4),
       S&P500_LAG_5 = lag(value, n=5))
```

How could I reduce this, (and also probably make it more efficient) and create a function for this that takes as inputs the symbol (so that I can scale this method to other symbols) and outputs the lag value of the symbol I pass on as an input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We could use `shift` from `data.table` that can take multiple values for `n`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,paste0("S&P500_LAG_", 1:5) :=  shift(value, n = 1:5)]
```

If there are multiple `symbol`s in a single column, then do a group by symbol

```
setDT(df)[,paste0("symbol_LAG_", 1:5) :=  shift(value, n = 1:5), by = symbol]
```

---

In `tidyverse`, one approach is to `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(1:5, ~ df %>%
              transmute(!! str_c("S&P500_LAG_", .x) := lag(value, n = .x))) %>%
   bind_cols(df, .)
```

With multiple symbols

```
map_dfc(1:5, ~ df %>%
              group_by(symbol) %>%
              transmute(!! str_c("symbol_LAG_", .x) := lag(value, n = .x))) %>%
   bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: For the multiple symbols `tidyverse` solution @akrun you're missing a `%>%` but then when I got it to run it kept producing annoying extra columns so I actually would up going this way which is 90% your solution with a small tweak. `map_dfc(1:5, ~ df %>%
group_by(symbol) %>%
mutate(!! str_c("symbol_LAG_", .x) := lag(value, n = .x))) %>%
  select(symbol, value, contains("symbol_LAG_"))
`